# Pi 3 Xorg.cond.d missing and need to swap the axis for the eGalax USB touchscreen

Tags: touchscreen, xorg, troubleshooting

I have a problem: `xinput_calibrator` doesn't work properly. After I touch 4 points my touchscreen's X and Y axis stay swapped. And I can not apply changes manually in the `Xorg.conf.d` directory because its missing in `etc/x11` and in `usr/share/x11` and `usr/lib/` everywhere.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Create this directory yourself in `/etc/X11` and put your calibration file there. Pay attention to the case: it's `xorg.conf.d`, not `Xorg.conf.d`!